# Exception while creating initiated flow [errorCode=1i4tu3y]

Tags: corda

When I try to respond to a flow, I get the error:

```
Exception while creating initiated flow [errorCode=1i4tu3y] statemachine.SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.onSessionInit - Exception while creating initiated flow [errorCode=1i4tu3y]
java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package com.example is sealed
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.getAndVerifyPackage(URLClassLoader.java:399) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.definePackageInternal(URLClassLoader.java:419) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
```

Answer (score 2):

Corda has recently enabled jar-sealing by default, this means that packages are no longer allowed to span multiple cordapps.

To fix this, make sure that no classes are defined as being in the same package, whilst being located in different cordapps.